# How to connect two sections of a mesh (sawed off shotgun)

Tags: mesh

I was wondering how I could connect the grip of my shotgun to the body like image one instead of the way i have it where it is just laying on the object.(check picture two)

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdGdT.png]

Comment: I guess your question is too vague and too broad, what have you tried and why don't you succeed, what is the specific problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 1):

To join 2 separated meshes press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in *Object Mode*. If you want to split them press instead <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but what I need to know how to do is how to connect the grip seamlessly to the body like in the first image of the finished shotgun.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the grip to be seamless, I think that you've got a couple of options:

1) In Edit mode, select the "back" faces of the front of the gun (where it needs to turn into grip) and extrude the grip directly from it to replace the stock that you've already made (or at least the central round core).  As you extrude the new stock out, you can start transitioning the shape to be more rounded. This is probably the cleaner approach but is more work.

2) You can use a Boolean Union modifier to join the current stock to the front half of the gun (make sure that the two meshes have some overlap for this to work correctly).  Then, you can go into Sculpt Mode, enable Dyntopo, and use the Smooth tool to ease the transition from barrel section to stock section.  If you want a more verbose description of this process, let me know and I'll type it up.